# Counting unique words of a minimum length in a string

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I have to write a function which takes 2 variables that is a sentence and a number. The function should return the number of unique words in the string that is equal or larger than the number. The example result should be :

```
>>> unique_func("The sky is blue and the ocean is also blue.",3)
    6
```

All I can think about the solution is

```
def unique_func(sentence,number):
    sentence_split = sentence.lower().split()
    for w in sentence_split:
        if len(w) >= number:
```

Now I don't know how to continue my solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from string import punctuation

def unique_func(sentence, number):
    cnt = 0
    sentence = sentence.translate(None, punctuation).lower()
    for w in set(sentence.split()):
        if len(w) >= number:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt
```

Or:

```
def unique_func(sentence, number):
    sentence = sentence.translate(None, punctuation).lower()
    return len([w for w in set(sentence.split()) if len(w) >= number])
```

Comment: I like the first solution but it will return 7 instead of 6 because I believe the 'blue' and 'blue.'is 2 different words. How to solve that?

Comment: @Artsiom Rudzenka use `string.punctuation`, you forgot all of these: `'#"%$\'&)(+*/;:=<?>@[]\\_^`{}|~'`

Comment: @ArtsiomRudzenka How about making `res` a `set` in the first place? There is no need for it to be a `list` anyway

Comment: Also this line: `w = w.strip('')` has absolutely no effect since you are stripping nothing

Comment: @jamylak, yes, my fault, forgot to remove it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint:

```
>>> set('The sky is blue and the ocean is also blue'.lower().split())
{'is', 'also', 'blue', 'and', 'the', 'sky', 'ocean'}
>>> len(set('The sky is blue and the ocean is also blue'.lower().split()))
7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> def unique_func(text, n):
        words = (w.strip(punctuation) for w in text.lower().split())
        return len(set(w for w in words if len(w) >= n))


>>> unique_func("The sky is blue and the ocean is also blue.",3)
6
```