# How to return the number of words in the string s that have length n (python)?

Tags: python

For a homework assignment, I am suppose to implement a function `numLen()` that takes a string `s` and an integer `n` as parameters, and returns the number of words in the string `s` that have length `n`. Words in the string are non-space characters separated by at least one space.

an example would be to input:

```
>>> numLen("This is a test", 4)
```

and get 2 because there are 2 words in the string that have 4 characters.

I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: This is easily done in python.  Look into the split() method and the len() method.

Comment: [Fellow student of yours?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127550/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-times-a-word-is-of-len-n-in-python)

Comment: And one more!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051777/counting-unique-words-of-a-minimum-length-in-a-string  My god, I wonder if this teacher knows that nobody in their class wants to learn anything.

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean to ask for the answer, but rather how to begin.

Comment: @JasonRay  You begin by trying something, anything, yourself.  A google search for what you're looking for would have pointed you in the right direction.  The Python documentation has everything you need to do your homework.  Your assignment is trivial and you didn't even try.  The same can be said for at least 3 of your classmates.

Answer (score 4):

Split the string into words with [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), iterate over the words, compare their length to the given number, return the count.

Here's a compact implementation using some builtins:

```
In [1]: def numLen(s, n):
   ...:     return sum(1 for w in s.split() if len(w) == n)
   ...: 

In [2]: numLen("This is a test", 4)
Out[2]: 2
```

You can exercise by building a version on your own along the lines of

```
def numLen(s, n):
    words = ... # build a list of separate words
    i = 0 # a counter for words of length n
    for word in words:
        # check the length of 'word'
        # increment the counter if needed
    # return the counter
```

Comment: `sum(len(w) == n for w in s.split())` is even more smaller.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary True, that's a nice once.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Agreed that is the better solution! That is what **should** be there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174392/is-it-pythonic-to-use-bools-as-ints

Comment: @jamylak Even Guido himself answered on that page. :)